# Operator overloading in Linq queries

Tags: linq

Operator overloading is working perfect in C# code, since I am trying in the following way.

**

```
public class HostCode 
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public static bool operator ==(HostCode hc1, HostCode hc2)
        {
            return hc1.Code == hc2.Code;
        }
        public static bool operator !=(HostCode hc1, HostCode hc2)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }**
```

I have a clas called HostCode and it contains 2 overloading methods (one for '==' and another for '!=')
And I created a collection of Host Codes below.

```
        **var hostCodes = new List<HostCode>()
        {
            new HostCode(){ Code = "1", Name = "sreekanth" },
            new HostCode(){ Code = "2", Name = "sajan" },
            new HostCode(){ Code = "3", Name = "mathew" },
            new HostCode(){ Code = "4", Name = "sachin" }
        };**

        ***var hc = new HostCode() { Code = "1", Name = "sreekanth" };***

        ***var isEq = hostCodes[1] == hc;***
```

when I am trying like above, the respective operator method fired in HostCode class (in this case it is '=='). So that I can write my custom logic there.

But if Iam trying with a Linq query as below, it is not firing. But in this case also Iam comparing 2 objects having same type.

```
**var isEqual = from obj in hostCodes where (HostCode)obj == (HostCode)hc select obj;**
```

Can anyone please help me to find out a way which I can compare 2 objects by Linq queries?

Comment: Go here for your answer - http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) or override [equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for this purpose.

```
public class HostCode 
{
....
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            return obj as HostCode == null ? false : (obj as HostCode).Code == Code;
        }
}
```

And IEqualityComparer usage is when you have some equality on object and in some functions like Contain, ... you want use some specific equality:

```
public class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<HostCode >
{

    public bool Equals(HostCode x, HostCode y)
    {
        return y.ID == x.ID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: **And override `GetHashCode`!**

Comment: @SLaks, Yes, I'd forgot it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is "how should I compare them for this to work" I would answer "you should overload and use `.Equals()` instead of `==`"

And what's with your overload definition of `!=`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: As I said, "Since your question is 'how should I compare them for this to work' I would answer 'you should overload and use .Equals() instead of =='", but this (ancient) question is jabberwocky